Isomorphism between spectrum of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1_{[y_0:y_1]}}[y_0^2t,y_0y_1t,y_1^2t]$ and the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)$
Let $\mathbb{P}^1$ be the projective line over a base field $k$, with homogeneous coordinates $[y_0 : y_1]$. Consider the sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$-algebras $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}[y_0^2 t, y_0 y_1 t, y_1^2 t]$, where $t$ is just a variable to keep track of the grading.

I want to show that the relative spectrum $\operatorname{Spec}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}}(\mathcal{A})$ is isomorphic to the line bundle $L_2$ given by the locally free sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)$, by checking that the line bundle transition functions are the same.

I want to do this by checking that the transition function of $\operatorname{Spec}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}}(\mathcal{A})$ over $\{ y_1 \neq 0 \}$ to over $\{ y_0 \neq 0 \}$ is $(\frac{y_1}{y_0})^2$, the same as for $L_2$. Another way of saying this is that $L_2$ is isomorphic to the gluing of $\operatorname{Spec} k[\frac{y_0}{y_1},x_1]$ and $\operatorname{Spec} k[\frac{y_1}{y_0},x_0]$ via the isomorphism $\operatorname{Spec} k[\frac{y_0}{y_1},\frac{y_1}{y_0},x_1] \cong \operatorname{Spec} k[\frac{y_0}{y_1},\frac{y_1}{y_0},x_0]$ that sends $y_0$ to $y_0$, $y_1$ to $y_1$, and $x_0$ to $(\frac{y_1}{y_0})^2 x_1$.
We know $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\{ y_0, y_1 \neq 0 \})[y_0^2 t, y_0 y_1 t, y_1^2 t]$ is isomorphic to $k[\frac{y_0}{y_1},\frac{y_1}{y_0}][y_0^2 t, y_0 y_1 t, y_1^2 t] = k[\frac{y_0}{y_1},\frac{y_1}{y_0}][y_1^2 t] = k[\frac{y_0}{y_1},\frac{y_1}{y_0}][y_0^2 t]$. However, I am strugling to use this to define isomorphisms to $k[\frac{y_0}{y_1},\frac{y_1}{y_0},x_1]$ and $k[\frac{y_0}{y_1},\frac{y_1}{y_0},x_0]$ that glue by $x_0 \mapsto (\frac{y_1}{y_0})^2 x_1$.

Welcome new contributor. These are not isomorphic, since the zero section of the (geometric) line bundle is a copy of $\mathbb{P}^1$, and this cannot be a closed subscheme of an affine scheme.  Probably you want to prove that the affine scheme is the contraction of the zero section in the (total space of the) geometric line bundle.

Thank you @JasonStarr! Wouldn't it be similar to how the trivial line bundle $\mathbb{P}^1_{[y_0:y_1]} \times \mathbb{A}^1_x$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}{\mathbb{P}^1}}(\mathcal{O}{\mathbb{P}^1{[y_0:y_1]}}[x])$ ?

I'm just using that if $E \rightarrow X$ is a vector bundle, and $\mathcal{E}$ is its sheaf of sections, then $E \cong \operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}{X}}(S\mathcal{E})$, where $S\mathcal{E}$ is the symmetric algebra. And I am guessing that the symmetric algebra of $\mathcal{O}{\mathbb{P}^1{[y_0:y_1]}}(2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}{\mathbb{P}^1{[y_0:y_1]}}[y_0^2t,y_0y_1t,y_1^2t]$.

Now I understand: you are considering relative Spec, not Spec of the $k$-algebra generated by those monomials.
